# Positioning of element in html

Tags: html, css, positioning

Is it possible to position a parent element relative to its child??

I mean, for example: `<dt>` and `<dd>`, `<dt>` is positioned in the center of `<dd>`'s height because my `<dd>` have different height.

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: what is *dt* and what is *dd*?

Comment: Talking about size, however, that's the default behavior under certain circumstances

Comment: @Usman definition term and definition data. Pretty rare tag in the wild.

Comment: well the and would be NO , but i would like to know what your dt and dd are ??

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/dd

Comment: @JanDvorak : thanx , something new and helpful to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is possible to achieve with javascript, but logically, **you can't want** that.
It makes no sense to position parent relative to a child, because whatever the effect you want, it can be achieved in other way.

What you are asking conceptually is wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't it become a loop if we change parent position then child position will change accordingly!

Comment: Yes, but my point is that you cannot give a right answer to a question which is initself wrong.

Comment: Yup! So this thing is not possible!

Comment: It is possible with javascript. But its not a sign of good thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery height function. with use of each function you can achive this

http://api.jquery.com/height/
http://api.jquery.com/each/